# Moving through a Filestream line by line (without using StreamReader) (Visual C#)

Tags: c#, file, io

I have a file and I have to skip 4 lines from it then skip 2 bytes problem is if i use StreamReader, I can't move 2 bytes since there's no read by byte.. If i use FileStream i can't move through it line by line

I tried to read line by line using StreamReader and then get the stream using BaseStream property and move up 2 bytes but when I get the BaseStream, the position is back at the front of the file..

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Is this a binary file?

Comment: Can you just read byte by byte with the `FileStream` and count the newlines?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I think it's a textfile because the metadata is in plain english ( i can open it in a test editor)

Comment: @ShaneAndrade You know, i didn't think of that.. That could actually work i guess

Comment: If you define a "line" as some bytes bound by either `\n` or `\r\n` you can read bytes and for each of the line delimiters you found, you increment the line counter.

Comment: What are the two bytes you need to read? You sure you can't use `StreamReader.Read(char[], int, int)`?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead they are weird characters, i can't really tell. So i can't use that Read because i'm not exactly sure how many bytes a character is.. I have to read the 2 bytes because of a problem with DeflateStream in .NET..

Comment: @ShaneAndrade Took your advice and it's working.. I should've thought of that.. If you want, just drop an answer and i will set that as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just read byte by byte with the `FileStream` and count the newlines?

Comment: +1: Note that this is somewhat ok approach as long as encoding of the stream is known to be safe to never have `\n` as part of other character - true for ASCII/Utf8, not true for Utf16 and potentially other encodings.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a TextReader you can read your file line-by-line like so:

```
TextReader rdr = File.OpenText(sourceFile);
while (rdr.ReadLine() is string line)
{
    ProcessLine(line);
}
```

Skipping a line is simply a matter of calling `ReadLine` without doing anything with the result.